# Check if v-model is empty?

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, vue.js

I want to prevent if user didnt enter anything. I tried like this but its not working:

```
 if(this.comment === ' '){
       return;
  }
```

This is my entire method:

```
 postComment: function(user_id,article_id) {
                if(this.comment === ' '){
                  return;
                }
                else{
                var article_comments = {
                  title: this.comment,
                  upovotes: this.article_comments.upovotes,
                  downvotes: this.article_comments.downvotes,
                  user_id : user_id,
                  article_id: article_id
                };

                  this.comments.push({
                      title: this.comment,
                      downvotes: 0,
                      upvotes: 0
                    })

                    this.$http.post('/blog/article/' + article_id + '/comment', article_comments).then(function(response){

                    },function(response){

                  });

                }
                this.comment = "";
              },
```

In view i have this:

```
  <div class="col-md-11 col-sm-11 col-xs-11">
     <textarea  class="comment_input" placeholder="Join the discussion..." v-model="comment" @keyup.enter="postComment({{$current_user->id}},{{ $article->id}})"></textarea>
 </div>
```

Comment: You're checking if the user entered a space. If you want to check if they didn't enter anything it should be `if(this.comment == '')` - and what exactly is 'not working'? What errors do you get?

Comment: if(this.comment == ''){
            console.log('empty');
          }
          else{
            console.log('not empty');
          } i get that is not empty even if it is

Comment: maybe because im using keyup.enter??

Comment: Yeah, maybe you're inserting a new line when hitting enter. You should prevent the default action with `@keyup.enter.prevent="postComment(...)"`. Also you should trim the input before checking it in order to ignore whitespaces: `v-model.trim="comment"`. If it's still not working, see what `console.log(comment, comment.length);` gives you.

Comment: i added v-model.trim and @keyup.enter.prevent but again its not working, in respose i get comment like this: comment"
" , second " goes in another line

Comment: i get : 1 for comment.length

Comment: That's strange. Just tested your code localy and everything is working as expected. Are you maybe initializing the comment with a whitespace? e.g. `comment: ' '` instead of `comment: ''`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/132707/discussion-between-none-and-quasdunk).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First off, you are checking for `' '`, which is not a blank text but a whitespace. If you want to check for a blank text, it would be

```
if(this.comment === '')
```

or

```
if(this.comment.length == 0)
```

Second, you should trim the whitespace before and after the input:

```
if(this.comment.trim() === '')
```

Or, as of Vue 2.0+, you can use the [trim input modifier](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/forms.html#trim) directly within the markup:

```
<textarea v-model.trim="comment" ...>
```

And last but not least, you should listen for the `keydown` rather than `keyup` event so you get the input at the time you're pressing the key and not after the key already has modified the input by adding a new line. And since you want to handle this event yourself, you should prevent the default action:

```
<textarea @keydown.enter.prevent="postComment()" ...>
```